# Has there been any formal proof that documentation in general is incomplete and obsolete to a certain grade?

Tags: documentation

I'm a web developer and I'm currently once again in a situation where a partly clueless ops department requires a "complete" documentation required for technical support of our application by a third-party, including "every possible error situation". Since there is no common ground on what this third-party should be capable of (ops constantly talk about "a person from the street should be able to do it"), I consider such documentation impossible and my experience tells me that every documentation is obsolete and incomplete, even if just a bit. I can't help to wonder: has there been any study or maybe even a proof that this is actually the case? Maybe even Gödel's incompletness theorems could be applied here?

Comment: If you can get them to admit that no piece of software is bug free, I think you could define bugs as unknown error conditions and prove the incompleteness that way. Of course, it may backfire and have them refuse to ship until you've fixed every bug.

Comment: What exactly is an "ops department"?

Comment: @Ramhound operations, i.e. sysadmins

Comment: @NikolaiProkoschenko: even if you find such a "formal reference", when you throw such an argument into a discussion, expect that the other persons will take you not seriously and think you are a smart ass (no offense!).

Comment: FWIW, even if you had a formal proof, it would not be persuasive to pointy-headed bosses.

Comment: And of course, having a formal proof of impossibility doesn't necessarily mean that it isn't worthwhile. Microsoft Research's Terminator, which can decide Halting for a very large class of Windows drivers is incredibly useful, despite the fact that Alan Turing proved that it cannot possibly work every time. It has been productized and shipped as part of the Windows Driver Development Kit for years now, and probably saved billions of dollars in development cost and prevented security breaches.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any formal proof, but here are some suggestions to solve your real problem. You are thinking about this too much like a programmer. Don't take  "every possible error situation" literally, when we all know you can't possibly document things you are not aware of. In your mind it sounds like they are requiring a perfect document. Whether there is definitive proof or not, you've already concluded it is impossible in this situation.

Someone needs to have a discussion about what they are really asking for and what you are able to create and come to some agreement.

Even if a code base doesn't change, there are application where users adapt the functionality by doing things the designers never imagined. It will be difficult for a lot of support staff to think about different ways the app can be used and how to support it.  Example: I worked as head of support for a water billing software company and a customer asked one of our initial support staff people if they could bill for trash. It was a flat-rate and our app had the ability to customize the label on each fee. In my mind it was obvious, flat-fee call it whatever you want.

Your documentation may have to adapt a bit of an agile approach to keep it up to date. Maybe this could be in the form of a wiki or some other type of website you can maintain and update frequently.  Of course they want the entire thing written up front and be perfect, but that isn't going to happen. You will need to make corrections and additions and that is going to be an on-going fee they're trying to avoid. Ask the client how often they are able to read the directions for anything and fully understand it? Software is much more complicated than putting together a bookcase.

Comment: + 1 The elephant in the room is how to pitch the document. A 3rd party are unlikely to be au fait with the various technical and industry specific jargon used in most companies.

Comment: A small clarification: the documentation in question is just a prelude to the question, i.e. we try to work with the ops to make a sensible delivery, so there is no real problem in handling the situation (apart from having to at all). I just wondered whether there is something scientific we could refer to by name.

Answer (score 0):

Producing such documentation is theoretically possible if:

- The software remains static (or all changes are immediately documented)
- All possible exceptions are caught and logged with their exact location in the code
- The above exceptions have been caught in the wild and produce the expected output defined in the documentation

Forgive my crudeness, but you stand about as much chance of all this being true as a one legged man winning an ass kicking contest.

Code is rarely (if ever) perfect, documentation doubly so.

It sounds like your ops department is trying to absolve themselves of any responsibility if anything goes wrong. Errors happen despite best endevours and it is fantasy to try and convince yourself otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You could argue that *truly* complete documentation - documentation that describes *exactly* what the software does with *every* filesystem, network, and UI input and output and *every* error condition and corner case - is as detailed as the source code and effectively indistinguishable from source code.  After all, source code is nothing more than a machine-readable description of how the software should make all of those decisions.

I doubt your clients want the source code or want to pay you to duplicate the source code.  For bonus points, consider that a great deal of your application's behavior depends on its operation system, libraries, and frameworks and that *complete* documentation would therefore cover those as well.

Like [@JeffO](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/234409/3223) and [@DocBrown](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/234404/3223#comment468825_234404) said, though, taking this approach is probably applying overly literal programmer-thinking to a user relations question, and the better approach is to try to discover and address their underlying concerns.